# What is the proper way to access the active scene in a driver expression?

Tags: python, drivers, properties, scene

I tried to access the FPS setting of the render settings in a shader node through a driver expression.
The attempt was successful, but I got a warning and a tip saying:

> WARNING: Driver expression may not work correctly
>
> TIP: bpy.context is not safe for renderfarm usage

[image: Driver Settings screenshot from Blender Drivers Editor]

According to [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8598/how-to-set-active-scene-via-python) the proper way to set the active scene is through `bpy.context`.
Therefor, I assumed, that the proper way to get the active scene would be through `bpy.context` as well.
This warning however makes me feel like there is a more proper way to access scene data (like render settings) through drivers so they would also work in renderfarms.

So my question is:
How do I properly access this kind of data in a driver expression?

Comment: You'll have to modify the drivers namespace because the expression field can't directly acces the `context` See  [How can a blender driver python script access scene properties like FPS?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28269/how-can-a-blender-driver-python-script-access-scene-properties-like-fps)

Comment: @Gorgious thanks, that helps a lot! Seems like I was using too abstract search terms. Probably would have found that if I literally looked for my specific problem.

Comment: You can simply enter the word frame into expression, and it will refer to the current frame. To slow down, you can do, frame * 0.01